# Initializing Rails model from JSON - how to initialize child associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization

I am generating data which is to be stored in rails. I have exported the data as a serialized JSON string.

How can I automatically build a new object *and its child associations* from this string?  `Model.new(json_string)` throws an error because the children are hashes and not initialized.  Is the only option to loop through each object and initialize the children?  I feel like there might be some magic I'm not aware of here.

Example:

```
Child belongs_to :parent
Parent has_many :children

json_string = "{
  attribute1:"foo", 
  attribute2:"bar",
  children: [
    {attribute1:"foo"},
    {attribute1:"foo"}
    ]}"

Parent.new(json_string)

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Child(#79652130) expected, got Hash(#69570820)
```

Is there a way to initialize new children from my serialized object automatically?  The real problem includes three child levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `children=` does not work as the setter for a has many association expects an array of model instances and is not intended to be used to create associated records from a hash.

Instead use [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class Parent
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end
```

This will let you create children by passing the attributes as `children_attributes`:

```
json_string = '{
  "attribute1":"foo", 
  "attribute2":"bar",
  "children_attributes": [
    { "attribute1":"foo"},
    { "attribute1:""foo"}
  ]
 }'

Parent.new(JSON.parse(json_string))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for nested_attributes http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

```
#Parent.rb

accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
```

You have to transform the json to have a key called children_attributes(with the value the same array of children) for this to kick in.